# buttons.cm email buttons not working on fresh .html document

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm trying to setup an HTML email template with a button as the primary link

I have used the default code from the *Campaign Monitor* - [*Bulletproof email buttons*](https://buttons.cm/) button generator on a completely fresh .html document (*as posted below*) but when I send the email it just won't work, the button displays perfectly but you can't click on it.

The button behaves perfect in a chrome browser but doesn't seem to work anywhere else?

I've messed with some of the code but honestly not sure where to begin and can't find anyone who's been in the same position

Maybe these buttons only work within a CM campaign?

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Email button test</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><!--[if mso]>
          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1e3650" fill="t">
          <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif" color="#556270" />
          <w:anchorlock/>
          <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Show me the button!</center>
        </v:roundrect>
      <![endif]--><a href="https://"
      style="background-color:#556270;background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif);border:1px solid #1e3650;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Show me the button!</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find button.cm buttons a little fiddly to work with. Below is a rehash of the code I found on Email On Acid and it works perfectly across all email clients the same way, even in Outlook. You can either have a full colour button or a button with border.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #3498db; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;" valign="top" bgcolor="#3498db" align="center"> <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #3498db; border: solid 1px #3498db; border-radius: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #3498db;" title="Click here to start survey">Start survey</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Advantage is you dont have to change in two places.